Proving a discrete logarithmic inequality used for complexity of trees
The following inequality is useful for asymptotic analysis of searching a binary tree with n nodes:
$$\lceil log_2(n+1) \rceil - 1 \leq log_2(n)$$
Playing around on Desmos, I see that it is critical we restrict $n \in \mathbb{N}$; in $\mathbb{R}$ there is an interval of size 1 before every power of 2 which does not satisfy this inequality.
How do we prove the inequality for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as $n=2^k+j$ where $k\geq 0$ and $0\leq j<2^k$.  Thus, $$\lceil \log_2{(n+1)}\rceil = \lceil \log_2{(2^k+j+1)} \rceil \leq \lceil \log_2{(2^{k+1})} \rceil$$
$$= k+1 = \log_2{(2^{k})} + 1 \leq \log_2{(2^k+j)} + 1 = \log_2{(n)} + 1 .$$
